# Prove that $x_n=1+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{3}{16}+...+\frac{n}{4^{n-1}}$ converges

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

so i have got a sequence $$x_n=1+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{3}{16}+\frac{4}{64}+...+\frac{n}{4^{n-1}}$$
and i have to prove that it actually converges to some point, just by looking at it, it is clear to me that it does converge, if i would take its limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{n}{4^{n-1}}}$$

as n increases the numerator becomes actually less than the
denominator, from that point it would converge, but how would i prove it.

Comment: You can use the integral test for this.

Comment: HINT: $n < 2^n$ for n more than 1.

Comment: Use the ratio test.

Comment: A [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use comparison:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{k}{4^{k-1}}}<\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{4^{k-1}}=4\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{2}{4}\bigg)^k$$

Comment: Ok thank you, but wouldn't be $\frac{1}{4^{-1}}$ be 4, so it would be 4 times the sum

Comment: @user122673 Thanks, corrected

Answer (score 2):

With a few tools that the OP probably doesn't have yet, we can also find the actual limit:

It is well known that $$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \text{ when } |x|<1$$
Differentiating this, we get
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}, $$
which is just your series if we set $x=1/4$.

Since $|1/4|<1$ and differentiation doesn't change the radius of convergence, your series converges, and the limit is $\frac{1}{(1-1/4)^2} = \frac{16}{9}$.

Answer (score 0):

the series $\sum (x_n-x_{n-1})$ converges, because

$$x_n-x_{n-1}=\frac n{4^{n-1}}\leq\frac1{2^{n-1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{4^{n-1}}dn=\frac{2ln(2)+1}{4ln(2)^2}$
and
$\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{1}^t\frac{n}{4^{n-1}}dn=\frac{2ln(2)+1}{4ln(2)^2}$

(Integral test)

Answer (score 0):

By induction the partial sums are $\frac{16*4^{n-1} - 3n -4}{9*4^{n-1}}$, which clearly approaches $\frac{16}{9}$ as $n$ goes to infinity.